# Automatically replace C++ operators

Tags: text-editing, replace

In some projects I'm working with, there are coding rules that don't allow C++ operators such as `==` (for fear of being confused with `=` I suppose, but oh well...). Instead, special macros such as `_EQ_` have to be inserted, which `#define` to `==`. There are other `#defines` as well, such as `_SH_LEFT_`, `_BITAND_` and so on.

Needless to say, this is all quite tedious to write and I would love to have a meachanism that makes me type `==` as I'm used to and have it automatically replaced by `_EQ_`.

I tried `abbrev-mode`, but as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71103) explains, abbrevs can only be defined for words, and I don't really want to change the definition all the required syntax entries. Also, it would be nice if I don't have to type a space after the keyword, but have the macro appear as soon as I hit the last char of the "forbidden" sequence.

Is there any way to achieve this, maybe a "more aggressive" abbrev-mode or some package?

EDIT: Here are some replacements that need to be performed:

```
I type:            I want:        
=                  =              (works with key-combo)
==                 _EQ_           (works with key-combo)
&                  _BITAND_       (works with key-combo)
&&                 _AND_          (works with key-combo)
|                  _BITOR_        (works with key-combo)
||                 _OR_           (works with key-combo)
!                  _NOT_          (works with key-combo)
!=                 _NOT_EQ_       (doesn't work with key-combo)
```

Comment: I think `_BITAND_` is rather problematic since `&` is also the reference operator.

Comment: @Tobias: You're right. Because _BITAND_ is rather rare, I'd exclude it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define a dedicated input-method, unless you're already using one.

```el
(quail-define-package "C++-operator" "C" "Cop")

(quail-define-rules
 ("==" ["_EQ_"])
 ("&" ["_BITAND_"])
 ("&&" ["_AND_"])
 ("|" ["_BITOR_"])
 ("||" ["_OR_"])
 ("!" ["_NOT_"])
 ("!=" ["_NOT_EQ_"]))
```

Activating it with `C-u C-\ C++-operator RET`. Note that you can still insert the original characters by using <kbd>C-q</kbd> as a prefix. (Just an idea I had and posted it, beeing suprised that it seems to work so easily.)

You can activate this automatically for c++-mode in the following way:

```el
(defun my-activate-C++-operator ()
  (interactive)
  (quail-activate "C++-operator"))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook  'my-activate-C++-operator)
```

Comment: That works nicely! How can I activate this mode automatically when I enter C++-mode?

Answer (score 3):

There is [key-combo](https://github.com/uk-ar/key-combo) which allows for the desired behavior

```lisp
(key-combo-define c++-mode-map  "="  '("= " "_EQ_ " "=="))
```

As I understand it, this is not straightforward with key-combo. What I would do is just:

```lisp
(key-combo-define c++-mode-map "!"  '("! " "_NOT_EQ_ "=! "))
```

After all, it's easier to press "!!" than "!=" and shouldn't conflict with C++ syntax as far as I know. 
You can also put a function in the list supplied as third arg to `key-combo-define`.

So you could do:

```lisp
(defun insert-noteq-or-eq ()
  (if (eq (preceding-char) ?\!)
      (progn 
        (backward-delete-char 1)
        (insert "_NOT_EQ_ "))
    (insert "=")))

(key-combo-define c++-mode-map "="  '(insert-noteq-or-eq "_EQ_ "))
```

This leads to the undesired behavior of the "!" reappearing when pressing "=" after "_NOT_EQ_ " has been inserted, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely for `==`, but what about other macros? Can I also have `!=` replaced by `_NOT_EQ_` etc.? I edited the original question to clarify that those are also needed.

Comment: You can automatically activate the method proposed by politza in the following way:

Comment: which way...? :P

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I added it to the answer.